# The limitation of derivative of modified Bessel function of second kind

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, bessel-functions

The final result I draw is related to the derivation of modified Bessel function of the second kind. But I can not solve it. Are you willing to help me? Thank all

$I = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\frac{{{K_0}(a\sqrt x )}}{{{K_0}(b\sqrt x )}}$ 
which *a* and *b* are real numbers

Comment: By exploiting the asymptotic expansion of $K_0$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin, if $a,b$ are positive numbers the limit as $x\to 0^+$ is either $+\infty,0$ or $-\infty$ according to $a<b, a=b, a>b$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!